# How to get downloadable product links after successfull order

Tags: url, download, magento, hyperlink, product

After a successfull order I would like to propose directly the downloadable URL for products buyer bought in the success.phtml file.

I wrote this piece of code to know product's values of the latest order:

```
// Get the latest Order ID
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load(Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastOrderId());
// Get every products on the latest order
$items = $order->getAllItems();

// Loop the products
foreach ($items as $item){
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->setStoreId($order->getStoreId())->load($item->getProductId());
    // HERE I NEED FUNCTION TO GET DOWNLOADABLE URL LINK
}
```

Comment: First - When you can just send them to their customer account where all this work is already done for you, why bother with this?

Second - if you just can't cope with this functionality already being in the users account page, have you looked at the code that displays the downloadable product links and tried to model your code after theirs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution, here it is:

First, create a new .phtml file in template/downloadable/ , I called mine downloadablelist.phtml

Then copy all of template/downloadable/customer/products/list.phtml in our new downloadablelist.phtml

This will give us a copy of the customer account my downloadable products list.

Call our block in success page :

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('downloadable/customer_products_list')->setTemplate('downloadable/checkout/downloadablelist.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>
```

Now I cleaned up what I don't need from the product list. I removed the table and added a ul instead.

Next is to show only the products that are made from the last order.

```
<?php
$_items = $this->getItems();
$orderId = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastRealOrderId();
if(count($_items)):
$_group_id = Mage::helper('customer')->getCustomer()->getGroupId();
echo '<p><strong>'.$this->__('Downloadable products').' : </strong></p>'; ?>
<ul style="margin-left: 30px; list-style: disc;">
        <?php foreach ($_items as $_item):
            $itemOrderId = $_item->getPurchased()->getOrderIncrementId();
            if($itemOrderId == $orderId) {?>
            <li><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_item->getPurchased()->getProductName()) ?> - <a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('downloadable/download/link/', array('id' => $_item->getLinkHash(), '_secure' => true)) ?>" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('downloadable')->__('Start Download') ?>" <?php echo $this->getIsOpenInNewWindow()?'onclick="this.target=\'_blank\'"':''; ?>><?php echo $_item->getLinkTitle() ?></a></li>
            <?php }
            endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I changed the url the original downloadable file had to :

```
href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('downloadable/download/link/', array('id' => $_item->getLinkHash(), '_secure' => true)) ?>"
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
$links = Mage::getModel('downloadable/link_purchased_item')->getCollection()
 ->addFieldToFilter('order_item_id', $item->getId());
foreach ($links as $link) {
 echo Mage::helper('downloadable')->__('download') .
  $this->getUrl('downloadable/download/link', 
  array('id' => $link->getLinkHash(), '_store' => $order()->getStore(), 
  '_secure' => true, '_nosid' => true));
}
```