# Adding downloadable links on success page

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.5

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get downloadable product links after successfull order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2561774/how-to-get-downloadable-product-links-after-successfull-order)

I wonder if it's possible to add multiple download links on Magento success page after ordering.

I am able to get one working link to a downloadable file with this code:

```
$incrementId = $this->getOrderId();

$linkPurchased = Mage::getModel('downloadable/link_purchased')->load($incrementId, 'order_increment_id');

$downloadableItems = Mage::getResourceModel('downloadable/link_purchased_item_collection')->addFieldToFilter('purchased_id', $linkPurchased->getPurchasedId());
foreach ($downloadableItems as $item) {

$links = Mage::getModel('core/url')->getUrl('downloadable/download/link', array('id' => $item->getLinkHash(), '_secure' => true));
echo $this->__('Download').' le <a href="'.$links.'" target="_blank">file</a>';
```

It gives me one perfect link on success page even if my order had multiple items.

Problem: 
The object in $linkPurchased have only one item.

Why is

```
Mage::getModel('downloadable/link_purchased')->load($incrementId, 'order_increment_id');
```

returns only one item?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution, here it is:

First, create a new .phtml file in template/downloadable/ , I called mine downloadablelist.phtml

Then copy all of template/downloadable/customer/products/list.phtml in our new downloadablelist.phtml

This will give us a copy of the customer account my downloadable products list.

Call our block in success page :

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('downloadable/customer_products_list')->setTemplate('downloadable/checkout/downloadablelist.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>
```

Now I cleaned up what I don't need from the product list. I removed the table and added a ul instead.

Next is to show only the products that are made from the last order.

```
<?php
$_items = $this->getItems();
$orderId = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastRealOrderId();
if(count($_items)):
$_group_id = Mage::helper('customer')->getCustomer()->getGroupId();
echo '<p><strong>'.$this->__('Downloadable products').' : </strong></p>'; ?>
<ul style="margin-left: 30px; list-style: disc;">
        <?php foreach ($_items as $_item):
            $itemOrderId = $_item->getPurchased()->getOrderIncrementId();
            if($itemOrderId == $orderId) {?>
            <li><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_item->getPurchased()->getProductName()) ?> - <a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('downloadable/download/link/', array('id' => $_item->getLinkHash(), '_secure' => true)) ?>" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('downloadable')->__('Start Download') ?>" <?php echo $this->getIsOpenInNewWindow()?'onclick="this.target=\'_blank\'"':''; ?>><?php echo $_item->getLinkTitle() ?></a></li>
            <?php }
            endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I changed the url the original downloadable file had to :

```
href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('downloadable/download/link/', array('id' => $_item->getLinkHash(), '_secure' => true)) ?>"
```

Thank you